# Display an image alt or title below the image and in h1 html tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, magento

I've got an image carousel in a site. I want to display the image alt tag or title below the image when I do mover over. At the same time I want to display that same name in another h1 tag.

The code is in PHP and Magento implementation. I know it is a simple trick. But I tried all the codes using jQuery after, append and replacewith functions. These functions are working. But I couldn't display the alt or title name.

Php Code:

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango alt">
<?php 
// products 
if(!isset($CatID))
$CatID = 10; // Set to classic collection if empty;
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($CatID);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)//enabled
        ->addCategoryFilter($_category);
foreach($products as $index=>$prod):
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
echo '<li style="border: none;">
<a class="thumbActImg1" href="'.$product->getProductUrl().'" data-rel="'.(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_resize, $_resize).'" alt="'. $product->getName() .'">
<div class="thumbActImg2">
<img src="'.$product->getThumbnailUrl(80, 80).'" alt="'. $product->getName() .'" />        
</div>
</a>
</li>';
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(this,'img.thumbActImg2').after('<div class="pname"><?php echo     $product->getName()?></div>');
jQuery('#pro_name h1').replaceWith('<h1><?php echo $product->getName()?></h1>');
```

Right now, I used php echo in order to display name. But it displaying the current page product name instead of mover over image name.

Could anyone help me out please.

Comment: jQuery(this,'img.thumbActImg2').after('<div class="pname">Img alt comes</div>');
jQuery('#pro_name h1').replaceWith('<h1>Img alt comes</h1>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi,**

the PHP-Code is evaluated once, when the site is generated. So the `<h1><?php echo $product->getName()?></h1>` is always the same text.

You have to rewrite/get the current information from the image, when it's cycled (if I understand you). So here is what may work for you:

```
//insert the code, where the carousel is triggered
//get the alt attribute from image and replace h1 content
jQuery('#pro_name h1').html(jQuery('img.thumbActImg2').attr('alt'));
```

I hope this is what you're looking for, the problem isn't descripted very briefly.

Greetings Mat

Comment: @Harry_beginner: as you want to get the text when you go a mouse-over, you can add this code to the mouse-over event of the images in the carousel

Comment: I need to display the image alt under that image and in somewhere on the page within h1. But both should display whenever I do move the mouse on the image.

Comment: The above mentioned code works,but it displays only the first image's name to every image in that carousel.

Comment: I've fixed this problem. There was a problem with image attributes.